# Subgroups and homomorphism theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on the proof of the following:
Let $f: G \to K$ be a surjective homomorphism and let $N = \operatorname{ker}(f)$ be finite.  Prove that if $K$ has a subgroup of order $m$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $m|N|$.

My proof uses the fundamental theorem of homomorphism and then have $G/N$ is isomorphic to $K$. Then if $K$ has a subgroup of order $m$, $G/N$ also does. I wonder whether I can draw a conclusion from here say that: quotient group of $G$ has a subgroup of order $m$, so that $G$ has a subgroup of order $m|N|$. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The subgroups of $G/N$ are in bijection with the subgroups of $G$ containing $N$.

Comment: I still cannot get the point, can you give me more explanation? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to one of the isomorphism theorems, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then the subgroups of $G/N$ are in one to one correspondence with the subgroups of $G$ containing $N$.

In your case, since $K \cong G/N$ and $K$ has a subgroup of order $m$, we know that $G/N$ has a subgroup of order $m$ as well, call it $H$. Then $H=H'/N$, for some $H' \leq G$. By Lagrange's theorem, $|H||N|=m|N|=|H'|$. The subgroup $H'$ is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the elegant proof! I think the isomorphism theorem you mentioned is the Correspondence theorem. Is that right?

Comment: @Evan That is correct